# Note Board web part snippet for adding to the page layout

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, snippet

I am working on a custom page layout where I want to add the note board web part.
The web part should be added dynamically on the page that would be created using this layout.

I have used the following snippet for it but the web part does not come up.

> ```
>     <webParts>                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
>       <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
> <metaData>
>   <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SocialCommentWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
>   <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
> </metaData>
> <data>
>   <properties>
>     <property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">All</property>
>     <property name="HelpUrl" type="string" />
>     <property name="Hidden" type="bool">False</property>
>     <property name="MissingAssembly" type="string">Cannot import this Web Part.</property>
>     <property name="Description" type="string">Enable users to leave short, publicly-viewable notes about this page.</property>
>     <property name="WebPartPropertyDisplayItems" type="int">3</property>
>     <property name="Title" type="string">Note Board</property>
>     <property name="AllowHide" type="bool">True</property>
>     <property name="WebPartPropertyAllowNewComment" type="bool">True</property>
>     <property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool">True</property>
>     <property name="AllowZoneChange" type="bool">True</property>
>     <property name="TitleUrl" type="string" />
>     <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">TitleOnly</property>
>     <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
>     <property name="Width" type="string" />
>     <property name="WebPartPropertySpecifiedAddress" type="string" null="true" />
>     <property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string" />
>     <property name="HelpMode" type="helpmode">Modeless</property>
>     <property name="Height" type="string" />
>     <property name="AllowEdit" type="bool">True</property>
>     <property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string" />
>     <property name="Direction" type="direction">NotSet</property>
>     <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">True</property>
>     <property name="ChromeState" type="chromestate">Normal</property>
>   </properties>
> </data>
> ```

Please help.